# Error to write a more-lines formula with equation

Tags: equations, errors, mathspec

I am using latex (with TEXMAKER editor) in order to create this formula

[image]

I use this code, but i get an error message that I can't understand where I wrong

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{equation}
        P_{H}(x) = f[x_{0}] + f[x_{0},x_{0}](x-x_{0}) +\\
& f[x_{0},x_{0},x_{1}](x-x_{0})^{2} +\\
& f[x_{0},x_{0},x_{1},x_{1}](x-x_{0})^{2}(x-x_{1}) +\\
& f[x_{0},x_{0},x_{1},x_{1},x_{2}](x-x_{0})^{2}(x-x_{1})^{2} +\\
& \cdots +\\
& f[x_{0},x_{0},x_{1},x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n},x_{n}](x-x_{0})^{2}(x-x_{1})^{2}\cdots (x-x_{n-1})^2 (x-x_{n})
    \end{equation}
\end{center}
```

Comment: `equation` is for single line equations and never put it in a `center` environment.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to use the `align` environment, like so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
P_{H}(x) ={}&  f[x_{0}] + f[x_{0},x_{0}](x-x_{0}) + \\
& f[x_{0},x_{0},x_{1}](x-x_{0})^{2} + \\
& f[x_{0},x_{0},x_{1},x_{1}](x-x_{0})^{2}(x-x_{1}) +\\
& f[x_{0},x_{0},x_{1},x_{1},x_{2}](x-x_{0})^{2}(x-x_{1})^{2} + \dots + \\
& f[x_{0},x_{0},x_{1},x_{1},x_{2}, \dots, x_{n},x_{n}](x-x_{0})^{2}(x-x_{1})^{2} \dots (x-x_{n-1})^2 (x-x_{n})
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Note that this requires the `amsmath` package.

**Edit**: This makes the second line numbered, like in the image you posted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
P_{H}(x) ={}&  f[x_{0}] + f[x_{0},x_{0}](x-x_{0}) + \nonumber \\
& f[x_{0},x_{0},x_{1}](x-x_{0})^{2} + \label{some_label} \\
& f[x_{0},x_{0},x_{1},x_{1}](x-x_{0})^{2}(x-x_{1}) + \nonumber \\
& f[x_{0},x_{0},x_{1},x_{1},x_{2}](x-x_{0})^{2}(x-x_{1})^{2} + \dots + \nonumber \\
& f[x_{0},x_{0},x_{1},x_{1},x_{2}, \dots, x_{n},x_{n}](x-x_{0})^{2}(x-x_{1})^{2} \dots (x-x_{n-1})^2 (x-x_{n}) \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `=&` gives wrong spacing. Use `={}&`

Comment: Oops didn't notice that, thanks.

Comment: But this equation has no number...unlike the OP's example.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I edited the post to include that as well.